# Python comma assignments order

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was trying Python comma assignment to parallelly change the values of variables. I believe Python will evaluate the values of the expressions on the right-hand side first and then, assign those values to the variables on the left-hand side. One specific example is in this reverse linked list code:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        prev = None
        curr = head
        while curr != None:
            prev, curr.next, curr = curr, prev, curr.next
        return prev
```

`prev, curr.next, curr = curr, prev, curr.next` works perfectly fine. If I change the order to `prev, curr, curr.next = curr, curr.next, prev`, I expect my code works the same:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        prev = None
        curr = head
        while curr != None:
            prev, curr, curr.next = curr, curr.next, prev
        return prev
```

However, I got an error instead in the second code for that line:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
    prev, curr, curr.next = curr, curr.next, prev
```

which doesn't make sense to me because Python evaluates the right-hand side expressions first before assigning, which means the order of where I put the expressions shouldn't matter. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please edit your code in your question so it is a [mre] - anyone should be abale to make a __single__ copy/paste into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the same problem you see. So you need to include imports, and data and all functions/classes referenced. Make sure after you edit the code into your quetion you can do hat I describe to run your code.

Comment: If you assign None to curr, curr.next will raise the error.

Comment: If at any point you are evaluating and assigning the tuple (somenode, None, someothernode) from the RHS to prev, curr, curr.next then your curr pointer which is assigned before curr.next becomes None and will raise an error when you try to assign curr.next

Comment: Horrible idea.  Make your code easy for people to read.  Tricks reveal inexperience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that Python evaluates the right-side first; however, what's missing is that Python will evaluate *each side in order*. We can see what this means by breaking the two options down into individual assignment statements ([Full example on Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/valotexose.rb)):

```py
# First example:
def reverseList(head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    prev = None
    curr = head
    while curr != None:
        # prev, curr.next, curr = curr, prev, curr.next
        x = curr
        y = prev
        z = curr.next
        prev = x
        curr.next = y
        curr = z
    return prev
```

```py
# Second example:
def reverseList2(head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    prev = None
    curr = head
    while curr != None:
        # prev, curr, curr.next = curr, curr.next, prev
        x = curr
        y = curr.next
        z = prev
        prev = x
        curr = y
        curr.next = z
    return prev
```

The important part here is that in the first example, we assign the value of `curr.next` *before* we assign the value of `curr`, whereas in the second example we assign the value of `curr.next` after. What this means is that when we go to assign `curr.next`, we've already updated `curr`, so when the interpreter accesses `curr.next` again for another assignment it will pull the wrong reference back. The error occurs when you've set curr to `None`, and then after doing so, you then try to access `curr.next` to complete your reassignment operation.

A side note, try to refrain from using `next` as a variable name. As it's a builtin function, it can cause some confusion, though it's probably fine.

Comment: Where's the documentation of `next` as a keyword? Can't see it anywhere in the grammar https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html

Comment: @balmy Searching the web for "python next" found this: [Built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) The answerer didn't state it would be a keyword (afaik python would throw a syntax error when using a keyword in an unintended way), but a built-in function.

Comment: @exalted edited it - used to say keyword not builtin :-)